# Boostrap datepicker date open for various option

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

I am using Bootstrap datepicker. I have a drop down(ddinterval) with three option 'Select','Weekly' and 'Monthly'. I have a textbox for datepicker calender. In requirement, on selecting 'Weekly' option, datepicker should have a normal calender and on selecting 'Monthly' option, datepicker should have a calender with only day 1 to 28 enabled for all month.I tried below code but output is not consistent.
This whole functionality is in bootstrap medal popup.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var dates_avail = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28];

  function isAvailable(date) {
    var dt = date.getDate();
    if (dates_avail.indexOf(parseInt(dt)) != -1) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  $('.ddinterval').on('change', function(e) {
    $(".dpstartdatefrom").datepicker("destroy");
    if ($('.ddinterval').val() == "Monthly") {
      $('.dpstartdatefrom').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
        beforeShowDay: isAvailable
      }).on('changeDate', function() {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
      });
    } else if ($('.ddinterval').val() == "Weekly") {
      $('.dpstartdatefrom').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      }).on('changeDate', function() {
        $(this).datepicker('hide');
      });
    } else {
      $('.dpstartdatefrom').datepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.8.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css" />

<select class="form-control cmbcrinterval ddinterval" id="cmbcrinterval" name="cmbcrinterval">
  <option value="">Select</option>
  <option value="Weekly" >Weekly</option>
  <option value="Monthly" >Monthly</option>
</select>

<input type="text" readonly="true" class="form-control datePicker dpstartdatefrom" id="txtstartdatefrom" name="txtstartdatefrom">
```

Comment: Add your `html` + provide a live snippet.

Comment: @Pedram added html

Comment: your code seems working: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKpVdR What is issue?

Comment: @BhumiShah: This whole functionality is in bootstrap medal popup.

Comment: @Prak: i have added it to  bootstrap modal popup https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKpVdR. Still it is working. Create issue in fiddle

Comment: @BhumiShah: Many thanks, It was bootstrap version issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code:

https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/eKpVdR

And Bootstrap used is:

```
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css
```